# How to fix an error by installing plugins in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I try to download the Checkstyle Plug-in 8.40.0 in Eclipse, but it isn't work and show the error

> The following solutions are not available: Checkstyle Plug-in 8.40.0 (id=net.sf.eclipsecs.feature.group, site=https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs/update)

```
eclipse.buildId=4.19.0.I20210303-1800
java.version=14.0.2
java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_MD
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/rusustefan-vlad/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/rusustefan-vlad/.eclipse_keyring
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core
Error
Mon Apr 26 19:24:51 CEST 2021
Provisioning exception
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at https://dl.bintray.com/eclipse-cs/eclipse-cs/8.40.0/.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:396)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.fail(CachingRepositoryManager.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.addChild(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.<init>(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:775)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.operations.AbstractProvisioningOperation.addRepositories(AbstractProvisioningOperation.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.operations.ProfileChangeOperationComputer.computeInstallableUnits(ProfileChangeOperationComputer.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.operations.ProfileChangeOperationComputer.run(ProfileChangeOperationComputer.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Could you please help me with understanding this problem?)

Comment: try to open `https://dl.bintray.com/eclipse-cs/eclipse-cs/8.40.0/` in a browser

Comment: It's forbidden to be accessed through a browser but I think that doesn't rule out the possibility that maybe Eclipse is somehow whitelisted and you should be able to download that way but maybe I'm wrong.
OP could try and download it manually, [here are some options.](https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs/#!/install)

Comment: This seems to have been a temporary outage of the update site that provides the download of the Checkstyle plugin. The The Eclipse Marketplace is a catalog that does not host plugins itself, but points to update sites. In [this case](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/checkstyle-plug), the update site is a [composite p2 repository](https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs/update/compositeContent.xml) which links to the p2 repository mentioned in the error message. Currently, it is accessible for me, so I guess that it was only a temporary outage. Please try again.